# Paragraphs in Matrix field not showing on the frontend

Tags: matrix

I have a Matrix field with a Rich Text Cell Type. When I output it on the frontend there are no paragraph tags. How do I add them? Other tags (e.g. `<strong>` display fine).

[image]

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_faq"}
{matrix_faqs}
    <dt>{question}</dt>
        <dd>{answer}</dd>
{/matrix_faqs}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

EE 2.6.1

Matrix 2.5.6

Answer (score 2):

Go into Admin > Channel Administration > Channels > Edit Preferences (beside the appropriate channel). Under “Channel Posting Preferences”, make sure that the “Default HTML formatting in channel entries” setting is set to “Allow ALL HTML”.

Comment: Thanks @Brandon for the lightning quick response, but I can confirm I already have it set to "Allow ALL HTML" on the Channel. I've tried changing it and setting it back, but no effect.

Comment: In that case it sounds like a bug with EE’s RTE field. You would be far from the first person to have similar issues with it. Most people end up just going with a third party WYSIWYG fieldtype like Wygwam.

Answer (score 1):

To help you, try this.

Go to the following [db table](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/data/sql_manage_tables.html) and check that your paragraph tags are being saved: exp_matrix_data

If they dont exist then the issue is with matrix cell.

If the do exist, then check the source code of the rendered html page.

Comment: Thanks @dadonbike. I've checked the exp_matrix_data and there is no markup for paragraphs (`<p>`) in there. I can see other markup (e.g. `<b>`).

So the issue is with Matrix?

Comment: The gentleman here, Brandon Kelly has also given you a clue. Hes also the guy who wrote Matrix, so now you know the issue is with Matrix. Beyond that i cant help you.